# React: Using events to trigger functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm building a sidecart functionality on my website with real-time updates based around a Local Storage array containing cart items. I'm using events to detect changes but I'm having a hard time to update the subtotal price:

**YourCart.js:**

This is the upper part of the cart, it retrieves local storage items. It gets re-rendered every time items are modified in the Local Storage. When it re-renders, it also dispatches the `"updateSubtotal"` event.

```
  function YourCart() {

    //state to store the items retrieved from local storage
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
    //add a trigger state to re-render the cart items
    const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      //retrieve the items from local storage

      const cartItemsFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGEKEY)) || [];
      setCartItems(cartItemsFromStorage);

      //listens for AddToCart clicks, triggers re-render when clicks happen
      updateCartEvent.addEventListener('updateCart', updateCartlistener);

      //dispatches updateSubtotal every re-render
      updateCartEvent.dispatchEvent('updateSubtotal',  "subtotal update!" )
    }, [trigger]);

    //updateCart callback function
    const updateCartlistener = (event) => {
      //removes old listener before setting a new one (prevents leaks)
      updateCartEvent.removeEventListener('updateCart', updateCartlistener);
      setTrigger(!trigger);
    };
```

Still on the same component, I want to show how the useEffect gets triggered. Every item action (add, subtract, remove) is calling `updateLocalStorage()` which then updates the Local Storage and triggers the component re-render:

```
  /*function to update local storage with the updated cart items, after that
  trigger the component re-render with setCartItems*/
  const updateLocalStorage = (updatedCartItems) => {

    //updates local storage
    localStorage.setItem(LOCALSTORAGEKEY, JSON.stringify(updatedCartItems));  

    //toggle the trigger state to force a re-render
    setTrigger(!trigger);
  };

  //function to handle the removal of an item
    const remove = (itemId) => {
      removeFromGlobalState(itemId);
      const updatedCartItems = cartItems.filter((item) => item._id !== itemId);

      updateLocalStorage(updatedCartItems);
  };

  //function to handle the subtraction of quantity
  const subtract = (itemId) => {
    const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((item) => {
      if (item._id === itemId && item.quantity > 1) {
        item.quantity -= 1;
      }
      return item;
    });

    updateLocalStorage(updatedCartItems);
  };

  //function to handle the addition of quantity
  function add(itemId) {
    const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((item) => {
      if (item._id === itemId) {
        item.quantity += 1;
      }
      return item;
    });

    updateLocalStorage(updatedCartItems);
  };
```

**yourCartActions.js**

This is the lower part of the cart, it is the component that displays the total price. It listens for the `updateSubtotal` event and calls the `calculateTotalPrice()` function from my Local Storage code:

```
function YourCartActions(){

  //initialize subtotalPrice with an initial value
  const [subtotalPrice, setSubtotalPrice] = useState(calculateTotalPrice());

  useEffect(() => {
    //update subtotalPrice when the event is triggered
    const handleCartUpdated = () => {
      setSubtotalPrice(calculateTotalPrice());
      console.log("Subtotal Updated!");
    };

    //add an event listener for 'updateSubtotal' event
    updateCartEvent.addEventListener('updateSubtotal', handleCartUpdated);

    //cleanup the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      updateCartEvent.removeEventListener('updateSubtotal', handleCartUpdated);
    };
  }, []);
```

**The problem:**

The subtotal actually updates on real-time when items are added with my other `AddToCart` component and when removed with the `remove()` function, but it doesn't updates on real-time when I use the `add()` and `subtract()` functions (only if I refresh the page).

As you can see, I did set up a `console.log("Subtotal Updated!");` for every time `handleCartUpdated()` gets invoked, then I proceeded to click the `add()` and `subtract()` a lot of times and the `Subtotal Updated!` gets printed every time, so this means that the function to update the price is actually being called, but like I said, it only actually updates the total price when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `trigger` state. Your `useEffect` can use `cartItems` array as the dependency and it will update whenever the array is updated.

Since the `useEffect` hook is triggered whenever the array is modified, you can put the code that updates your local storage in this hook. You can read [how useEffect works in this official doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#useeffect).

YourCart

```js
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

// this hook stores into local storage
useEffect(() => {
   localStorage.setItem(LOCALSTORAGEKEY, JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}, [cartItems]);

// this hook is only executed once to update your cart items
useEffect(() => {
   const cartItemsFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGEKEY)) || [];
}, []);
setCartItems(cartItemsFromStorage);
```

However, to ensure you trigger the `useEffect` hook, you must update your array like this:

```js
function add(itemId) {
   const updatedCartItems = cartItems.map((item) => {
      if(item.id === itemId) {
         return {
            ...item,
            quantity: item.quantity + 1
         }
      }
   });
}
```

`map` returns a new array, so it will trigger your `useEffect` to run again.

---

You don't need to use a custom event listener to handle add/remove/update events in your cart. Please read this [React documentation on handling events](https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events#adding-event-handlers)

To ensure `CartActions` component calculates the subtotal properly, just pass your `cartItems` to it.

YourCart

```js
// ... other code
return (
   <YourCartActions cartItems={cartItems} />
   { /* other jsx elements */ }
)
```

YourCartActions

```js
function YourCartActions({ cartItems }) {
   const [subtotal, setSubtotal] = useState(0);
   
   useEffect(() => {
      setSubtotal(calculateTotalPrice()); // or just calculate here
   }, [cartItems])
}
//...other code
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the trigger state, your solution is much cleaner and I'll be using that. 

However, I already thought of rendering ```YourCartActions``` inside of ```YourCart``` but that'll cause some very nightmarish design issues, I also can't use context because my dumb beginner ass thought it would be "easier" to render components isolated rather than using app() (and I'm in too deep now to go back). 

If you can at least mention any other possible solution it would be so helpful, but if not it's ok, I'll suck it up and try to solve this design issue.

Comment: Lol! I accidently solved my issue by using a getGlobalState() function I had created on the Local Storage code and forgot about it. Thanks for the help, I'll be using your method to trigger my state change.